# extract title from a link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am using beautifulsoup to **scrape** a website but need help with this as I am new to python and beautifulsoup
How do I get VET from the following
"[[VET]]"

This is my code so far

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


#This is the Home page of the website
source = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///C:/Users/Aiden/Downloads/stocks/Stock%20Premarket%20Trading%20Activity%20_%20Biggest%20Movers%20Before%20the%20Market%20Opens.html').read().decode('utf-8')

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


#find the Div and put all info into varTable
table = soup.find('table',{"id":"decliners_tbl"}).tbody



#find all Rows in table and puts into varTableRows
tableRows = table.find_all('tr')
print ("There is ",len(tableRows),"Rows in the Table")
print(tableRows)

columns = [tableRows[1].find_all('td')]
print(columns)

a = [tableRows[1].find_all("a")]
print(a)

So my output from print(a) is "[[<a class="mplink popup_link" href="https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/VET/">VET</a>]]"
 and I want to extract VET out
```

AD

Comment: Could you please give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What is `"[[VET]]"` (a class name, etc.)? Could you show us your code so far?

Comment: give us the link,  your current code, and what VET is

Comment: Hi, Thank you for reply I have posted my code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! As others noted, it would help if we had a little more info about what's in your source file, or if you reduced that file to demonstrate the problem. 

My guess is that 'VET' is a link in a table in your html file, and your problem is that it prints [[VET]], but you don't want the brackets. Try changing the last assignment to `a = tableRows[1].find_all("a")`, that will remove one set of brackets, then you can remove the next one by adding `[0]`, but that only works if there is at least one element and you don't care if there are any others.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I worded the question badly  my output is "[[<a class="mplink popup_link" href="https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/VET/">VET</a>]]" and I need to get just VET from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a.text or a.get_text().

If you have multiple elements you'd need list comprehension on this function

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the reply, I was able to work it out using the following code

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('file:///C:/Users/Aiden/Downloads/stocks/Stock%20Premarket%20Trading%20Activity%20_%20Biggest%20Movers%20Before%20the%20Market%20Opens.html').read().decode('utf-8')


soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

table = soup.find("table",id="decliners_tbl")

for decliners in table.find_all("tbody"):
    rows = decliners.find_all("tr")
    for row in rows:
        ticker = row.find("a").text
        volume = row.findAll("td", class_="rightcell")[3].text
        print(ticker, volume)
```